# Linux start-stop-daemon directory error calling shell/python script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, start-stop-daemon

I am just getting acquainted with Linux and I cannot seem to get the `start-stop-daemon` to run a python script due to directory issues. In a linux file structure I have the files:

*~/test.txt*

```
THIS LINE IS A TEST
```

*~/test.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time

with open("test.txt") as f:
    while True:
        try:
            print("Hello World")
            print(f.readline())
            time.sleep(2) 
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            f.close()
            break
```

*~/test.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "SHELL SCRIPT SUCCESS" > /var/log/test.log
cd ~/
./test.py > /var/log/test.log
```

Upon calling `sudo bash ~/test.sh` from any directory the *test.log* is populated as expected with the stdout originating from *test.py*. For some reason, starting the following start-stop-daemon service script WILL generate a *test.log* but does NOT populate it with the stdout:

*/etc/init.d/test*

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:     Python test script
# Required-Start:   $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:    2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:     0 1 6
# Short-Description:    Prints out daemonized argument
# Description:      Creates output of argument
### END INIT INFO

DAEMON_DIR=/home/alex
DAEMON=$DAEMON_DIR/test.sh
DAEMON_NAME=test

DAEMON_OPTS="hello"
DAEMON_USER=root
PYTHON=/usr/bin/python

PIDFILE=/var/run/$DAEMON_NAME.pid

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start () {
    log_daemon_msg "Starting system $DAEMON_NAME daemon"
    #start-stop-daemon --start --background --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --user $DAEMON_USER --exec $PYTHON --startas $DAEMON 
    start-stop-daemon --start --background --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --chuid $DAEMON_USER --startas /bin/bash  /home/alex/test.sh
    log_end_msg $? 
}

do_stop () {
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping system $DAEMON_NAME daemon"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PIDFILE --retry 10
    log_end_msg $?
}

case "$1" in

    start|stop)
    do_${1}
    ;;

    restart|reload|force-reload)
    do_stop
    do_start
    ;;

    status)
    status_of_proc "$DAEMON_NAME" "$DAEMON" && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;

    *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$DAEMON_NAME {start|stop|restart|status}"
    exit 1
    ;;

esac
exit 0
```

Is this a directory issue that can be addressed within the `start-stop-daemon`?
Alternatively I'd be open to other methods of script servicing that can persist through a cold boot (i.e. no cron jobs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `cd` using an absolute path, for example `/home/alexjg/` instead of `~/`; the reason it was broken before is that in your example you're using `sudo` which keeps the home directory of the user running it. However when you're calling the bash script from init it will use root's home directory instead which doesn't contain `test.py`.

The file is created because the redirection is still succeeding; however because starting Python failed there was no output.

Comment: Changing `cd ~/` to an absolute path `cd /home/alex` still results in an empty *test.log*. Additionally wouldn't the line `echo "SHELL SCRIPT SUCCESS" > /var/log/test.log` prior to the `cd` force logging prior to calling *test.py*?

Comment: @AlexJG You're using a single `>` which means overwrite and not append.

Comment: Replacing both instances of `>` to `>>` led to `SHELL SCRIPT SUCCESS` being written to *test.log*! However, the `print` statements within *test.py* still aren't appearing.

Comment: give the python script a full path to 'test.txt'. where do you want the output

Comment: @Tamar I'm wondering why the script will not run without an explicit path to *test.py*, basically why doesn't executing the `start-stop-daemon` behave the same way as calling `bash ~/test.sh`? The way I understand it the daemon is doing the same thing

Comment: when you are not running the script within your environment, your environment variables are not presented. one of the, is your PATH environment variable, which tells bash where the executables can be found. in addition, the '~' magic characters finds your (alex) home dir, which is not the same when you run it with the init script (=root user, probably /root home dir). so you cannot trust anything that depends on environment variables. make sure you are not depending on them